# Peculiar behaviour of object destructuring

Tags: typescript, destructuring, typescript2.7

I have the following:

```
  @Action( RsRosCoughUiUpdate )
  rsRosCoughUiUpdate( { getState, patchState }: StateContext<IRs>, payload: IFormState ) {
    console.log( `classToPlain(payload) | ${JSON.stringify( classToPlain(payload) ) }` )
    console.log('PAYLOAD', payload)
    console.log('PAYLOAD STATUS', payload.status)
    console.log('PAYLOAD STATUS', payload['status'])
    console.log( `change-before | ${JSON.stringify( payload.change ) }` )
    console.log(classToPlain(payload))
    console.log( `change-after | ${JSON.stringify( payload.change ) }` )

    let {change, dirty, pristine, status, target, touched, untouched} = payload

    console.log(change, dirty, pristine, status, target, touched, untouched)

    const nextState = produce( getState(), draftState => {
      let {change, dirty, pristine, status, target, touched, untouched} = payload
      console.log( `change | ${JSON.stringify( payload.change ) }` )
//       draftState.ros.ui.cough = payload



//      draftState.ros.ui.cough =    {...payload}
//      draftState.ros.ui.cough.change = payload.change
//      draftState.ros.ui.cough.dirty = payload.dirty
//      draftState.ros.ui.cough.pristine = payload.pristine
//      draftState.ros.ui.cough.status = payload.status
//      draftState.ros.ui.cough.target = payload.target
//      draftState.ros.ui.cough.touched = payload.touched
//      draftState.ros.ui.cough.untouched = payload.untouched
    } )

    patchState( { ...getState(), ...nextState } )
  }
```

When the application runs, the console log is shown below:

```
classToPlain(payload) | {"payload":{"change":"add","dirty":true,"pristine":false,"status":"INVALID","target":"[cough->rs-ros]cmp","touched":true,"untouched":false}}
rs.store.ts:73 PAYLOAD RsRosCoughUiUpdate {payload: FormState}
rs.store.ts:74 PAYLOAD STATUS undefined
rs.store.ts:75 PAYLOAD STATUS undefined
rs.store.ts:76 change-before | undefined
rs.store.ts:77 {payload: {…}}payload: {change: "add", dirty: true, pristine: false, status: "INVALID", target: "[cough->rs-ros]cmp", …}__proto__: Object
rs.store.ts:78 change-after | undefined
rs.store.ts:82 undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined
rs.store.ts:86 change | undefined
```

Removing all the debug info and performing a console.log(payload) gives the following

[image]

Questions:
1. Why the destructured values always undefined?
2. Why does the dot traversal of the payload object graph always undefined?

Cheers

Comment: Can't say for sure... but it looks to me like the payload you want isn't the variable payload, but rather `payload.payload`

Comment: @Gerrit0 Tried that before without much success. It errors saying that payload is not a property on IFormState. See the graphic I just added. Cheers

Comment: That `IFormState` definition doesn't have a property named `payload` does not mean that your variable `payload` doesn't. TypeScript may protest, of course, according to the definition of `IFormState`, but, where does the `payload` value come from? A service? Maybe you're not getting what you are expecting, and so, either you get a TypeScript compilation error or you get `undefined` for properties at runtime. Remember that an interface is only a way to inform the compiler about the structure of data, it does not hold truth by itself. If the definition is wrong, you get unexpected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in my comment, you can see the problem here:

```
console.log('PAYLOAD', payload);
```

Now, if you check the console results, you get, for this log:

```
rs.store.ts:73 PAYLOAD RsRosCoughUiUpdate {payload: FormState}.
```

It says that `payload` is a `RsRosCoughUiUdpate`, an object that has a property called `payload` of type `FormState`. I assume that `FormState` is a type that complies with your `IFormState` interface.

So, of course:

```
console.log(payload.change);
```

shows `undefined`.

To get your values, your destructuring should be:

```
let {change, dirty, pristine, status, target, touched, untouched} = payload.payload
```

And maybe you should change the name of the `payload` variable, as it is not what you think it is.

Comment: Great analysis! You are so correct. The payload is of type RsRosCoughUiUpdate and contains the actual payload of type IFormState. I will rename to correct the confusion. Thanks